# how to monitor network usage

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! We are using ROS1 Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 with regular desktop version.

We have some processes using internet, for example,

- streaming some topics content to a commercial cloud server,
- Ntrip RTK for gps correction.

Now we want to monitor the bandwidth and data usage, so in Ubuntu System Monitor, there's a section "Network History" contains Total Received and Total Sent.

So our question is,
Does this total received/sent value include only those interaction with Internet, like the 2 processes mentioned above?
Or does this total value also include the data flow within ROS, like node publish/subscribe: node_A -> topic_1 -> node_B?

We have very limited knowledge of network.
If System Monitor is not the right tool, is there a better tool to monitor the data usage?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411304/how-to-monitor-network-usage/) by [Mingjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/122736/mingjie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2023-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) on 2023-01-12**:
Try using :

htop

**Comment by [Mingjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/122736/mingjie/) on 2023-01-16**:
I did a simple test for my question about System Monitor: I found that it does not include the publish/subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possible solution: Using psutil package in python, you can monitor individual ports/adapters for traffic, so if you want to monitor just the port to your internet router that is simple.

To answer your direct question about System Monitor, wouldn't it be simple to test this by getting data with and without that access to internet active?

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2023-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the command line tool `rostopic bw` to check the bandwidth used by a certain topic.
[Documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_bw)

---

Originally posted by [AlessioParmeggiani](https://answers.ros.org/users/94489/alessioparmeggiani/) with karma: 165 on 2023-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2